# Decrypting/Encrypting PGP in Load Runner Script for correlation/parameterization

Tags: encryption, scripting, performance-testing, loadrunner, pgp

One of the applications that we stumbled up on is a ThickClient Desktop application with WCF Webservices at the backend. We are able to record the communication using LR VuGen 11.52/12.02 which is in the form SOAP Requests.

We are facing a big challenge wherein the ThickClient sends out communication via PGP Encryption.

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----&#xD;
Version: BCPG v1.46&#xD;
&#xD;
KBRJxQLWTz6CiuqI9pV8pkuA41zdH8czrTOdsa2ChiXvhSjhSFcFNLZ742cZ9rE/&#xD;
tZ9Fg/4UGaNbC68oZi5OnTzcvP6JxIoUW9mA+xVcmnnbBUq2e7uTbySU2+eAZw9j&#xD;
1OGYj1ubLVYEq4kNYcauvKpF+XfkoCQxDVfn/5hIzPNUrdIhoNgPlrcosU6ZyMSE&#xD;
1wG9r3/P1ddnuhdQxn+rdEfxsk7BicJCbeCqaFpovKXbo4M/piquFMN96/Jfnoak&#xD;
RDc6VweQQMlbovz3v6jVEhXWJnAonVTWY5R2Z3Dz/HRgWkU40OdPb2PQIjvaOsIy&#xD;
qvQHMdwsn/+m6Pz8QRI9+RsGvvmhwHkE1t82tuqVZbUJL5g5+EZHAeHrbgnIyvgT&#xD;
DO6A4AO0gzkDwG1ey80skC3Zc77rD6FhzQrnS7Nc2GeQLVRe3PIs10OCMhqDI+n9&#xD;
fAFaTg93lcU=&#xD;
=lX0X&#xD;
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Is there a method or process by which we can decrypt such messages and correlate/parameterize required data and then repost the same to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.   You need the decryption and encryption keys.  You will also need an implementation of the PGP algorithm in C.   With all of those items in place you also stand better than fair chance of leveraging the DFE (Data format extentions) for Loadrunner to have the work of encryption and decryption handled on the fly.

References

http://cypherspace.org/openpgp/
http://claudihome.com/html/LR/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_web_data_format_extensions.htm